# PYTHONPATH issues with versioned package names outside of site-packages

Tags: python, pythonpath

In attempting to solve a package management issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600938/nested-pth-files-edit-pythonpath-issues), I learned I may have issues with the way I'm using `PYTHONPATH` to access packages outside of the site-packages directory.

I receive an import error when attempting to import modules from a package (say `wxPython`) from its versioned directory folder name (i.e. `wx-2.8-msw-unicode`) when said directory is not in the python site-packages directory.

To recreate the issue: Create a directory outside of the python directory, say `C:\foo`. Download `wxPython`, and place it in that directory (giving `C:\foo\wx-2.8-msw-unicode`). Add more if you like. Add the directory `C:\foo` to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Open a new python interactive shell and run

```
import sys
for i in sys.paths:
    print i
```

to verify that the path is there (which it is), then

```
import wx
```

I receive an Import Error. What am I doing wrong? Is this behavior correct?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001851/pythonpath-ignored

Comment: It seems that that article is discussing the order of directories getting added to sys.path. I'm not sure how it relates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand what you're saying, this is expected behaviour. `C:\foo` is in your Pythonpath, but it does not contain an importable wx module. For `import wx` to succeed, it has to find one of `wx.(py/pyc/pyd/dll/so)` or a directory `wx` containing the file `__init__.py`, directly in one of the directories on your Pythonpath.

The installer will normally sort out making sure this is in an importable location for you. If you want to do it yourself, you have to ensure that `wx` ends up in an importable location.

Comment: This is how I interpreted the usage of `PYTHONPATH` as well. I'll mark this as the correct answer within the next hour, unless another explanation is found.